# Having problem embedding strings into SQLite query in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a SQLite database with a datetime column like below and I do query using Python(import sqlite3):

[image]

First of all, the following query is successful:

```
sqlite_select_query = 'SELECT DateTime FROM myTable WHERE DateTime BETWEEN "2022-03-14 14:09:08" and "2022-03-15 17:04:51"'
```

But I want to make start and end dates user selectable and write the query in the following form:

```
startingDate = "2022-03-14 14:09:08"
endingDate =   "2022-03-15 17:04:51"

sqlite_select_query = 'SELECT DateTime FROM myTable WHERE DateTime BETWEEN '+startingDate+' and '+endingDate+'
```

But the above give the following error:

> SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

```
startingDate = "2022-03-14 14:09:08"
endingDate =   "2022-03-15 17:04:51"
```

Then I tried to add one more ' at the end as follows:

```
sqlite_select_query = 'SELECT DateTime FROM myTable WHERE DateTime BETWEEN '+startingDate+' and '+endingDate+''
```

But now the above doesn't select anything.

Comment: you are missing an ending '

Comment: @applesomthing Yes I replaced ' with " and same issues

Comment: Use parameter substitution to interpolate values; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/902836/5320906) for sqlite syntax.

Comment: @gajendragarg Tried and that doesn't select anything either.

Comment: Can someone help me they closed the question. And the link didn't help me either.

Comment: and encapsulating it?
('SELECT DateTime FROM myTable WHERE DateTime BETWEEN '+startingDate+' and '+endingDate+')

Comment: @applesomthing Gives EOL error

Comment: @gajendragarg Doesnt return anything

Comment: @snakecharmerb Parameter sub didnt work

Comment: Please vote to reopen the question.

Comment: @gajendragarg It doesn't return anything at cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)

Comment: Last try: `sqlite_select_query = f"""SELECT DateTime FROM myTable WHERE DateTime BETWEEN "{startingDate}" and "{endingDate}" """`

Comment: I'd consider voting to reopen if you [edit] the question to show how parameter substitution is not working.  String formatting is absolutely the wrong way to do this.